# IconIndex value of -101 in desktop.ini pointing to the second icon in DLL?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, desktop.ini

I have a folder which is displayed in Windows Explorer as:
[image]

Inside this folder the hidden desktop.ini has this content:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=@Shell32.dll,-12688
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\mydocs.dll
IconIndex=-101
```

This `mydocs.dll` actually contains exactly **TWO** icons, where the **second** one is the icon used by Windows Explorer to display the above folder.

So shouldn't the last line of the desktop.ini content be `IconIndex=1` (supposing Windows starts counting at 0) instead of `IconIndex=-101`?

I have tried to interpret the `-101` value as binary, hexadecimal, octal, but none was translating to a number which would represent the second icon.

So, how is the `-101` value pointing to the SECOND icon in `mydocs.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative IconIndex refers to the inverse of the **Resource ID**. See [this Microsoft dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153):

> In Windows 95, the Extract­Icon function was enhanced so that you
> could also specify an icon by its resource ID by passing its negative
> as the icon index.

See also the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticona).

In your case, the icon used has a resource ID: **101** and therefore it is shown as **-101**.
After checking my own mydocs.dll, It shows that the resource ID is 101 for the icon you displayed and resource ID: 100 for the first icon (folder with document).

Comment: Is this a general and RELIABLE rule that resource IDs in desktop.ini always start counting from `100`?

Comment: @user1580348 It is *not* a reliable rule. It depends on how the developers wrote the resource file for the application when they built the application. See [ICON resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information. The *resourceID* is a "Unique name or a 16-bit unsigned integer value identifying the resource."